# DLNA Media Server and external subtitles

Tags: server, mediaserver, video-streaming, upnp

I'm looking DLNA Media Server with the **features above**:

- Support most extended video formats.
- Reproduce external subtitles in client side.
- Open source or freeware software.

**USE CASE**:

- DLNA Media server installed and running on my PC.
- In my PC, I have /home/myprofile/videos directory where I store all my video files.

  - For example, game.of.thrones.s09.e06.mpg and game.of.thrones.s09.e06.srt
- Turn on my Smart-TV, connect to my DLNA Media Server (installed on my PC)
- Play game.of.thrones.s09.e06.mpg file and see the subtitles overlapped.

Finally, my question: **Is there some DLNA Media server that provides that use case?**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is not much options, official DLNA specification say nothing about external subtitles. There are two DLNA media servers:

1. Plex Media Server, it works by default with LG TV's and Samsung after installing official client on TV - https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/plexmediaserver/. My favourite media server, has a lot of features like media library with descriptions, watched/unwatched status
2. Serviio - http://www.serviio.org/, cannot tell how does it work

Comment: Thank you very much! Plex Media Server is the best one, it works in LG Tv's and it reproduces external subtitles in client side from server side. Perfect!!! 1000 points for you!!